# What is a larval-subject?

Tags: continental-philosophy, psychoanalysis, deleuze, deleuze-and-guattari

On the heading of this [blog](http://larval-subjects.blogspot.co.uk/2006/07/stuffed-by-obsessional.html):

> Larvae are creatures in a process of becoming or development that have not yet actualized themselves in a specific form. This space is a space for the incubation of philosophical larvae that are yet without determinate positions or commitments but which are in a process of unfolding.

Presumably this means a larval subject is a subject where emphasis is placed on a subject becoming something determinate - the subject proper.

Is this a Deleuzian term? It does seem rather like the language he would use.

Comment: It's really about Ruyer/Simondon and morphogenesis I think -- that there are some extreme transformations, involutions, etc., that an organism in an embryonic or 'larval' state can undergo which would be unendurable for the adult organism

Comment: And just in passing, Levi has a [newer blog over at wordpress](http://larvalsubjects.wordpress.com/)